# How do I create a console application in Visual Studio Express for Windows 8?

Tags: visual-studio, console-application

In VS Express for Windows 8, I am unable to create a console application. My understanding of C++ is very basic, and I would like to just work with a single C++ file.

Upon creation of a C++ file, I am able to edit the program, but not test. Can anyone either explain to me how to build the file, or create a console application project?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are different versions of Visual Studio 2012 Express.

`Visual Studio Express for Windows 8` is targeted against building software for Windows Store using the new tiled interface. It will not allow you to build console applications.

The version which you should use is called `Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop`, it covers more traditional Windows development including console applications.

Once you have installed Express for Windows Desktop launch it and create a C++ console application project. You can then select to build your solution from the `Build` menu, and run it from the `Debug` menu.

Answer (score 15):

I found a way to create a Console project no matter what version of VS Express you are using.

1. Create any type of project (i.e. A basic "class library" project).
2. Right-click the project in Solution Explorer and click Properties. You'll see a dropdown for "Output type". Select "Console Application".
3. Create a Main method somewhere as an entry point into the app. Doesn't matter what class you put it in.

   ```
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("We made a console app");
           Console.ReadKey();
       }
   }
   ```

I did this with "Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web", so I'm not absolutely certain what your mileage will be on other flavors.

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio express for desktop you can create a console application in the language of your choosing.  The following YouTube video provides a step by step tutorial for building console apps with links to detailed instructions to do the same.  Unfortunately the demo and instructions are in C# but the process is similar in C++ only syntax is different.

Also make sure that you are running the correct edition of Visual Studio Express.  The "Platform" that is required to create Console Applications is VS Express for Desktop.  Console Application template is not available in Visual Studio Express for Windows...

See this blog post for details on the VS Express Editions (Platforms)
http://www.prodataman.com/Blog/Post/97/What-can-you-get-for-FREE-with-Visual-Studio-Express-by-Edtion
[Create a Basic Console Application Visual Studio 2013 C# .Net - Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIhNea3_vPw)